# Convert back quaternion to value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some slider values to control the object rotation,

```
a = slidery.GetComponent<Yslider>().value;
b = sliderx.GetComponent<Xslider>().value;
c = sliderz.GetComponent<Zslider>().value;

join.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(a, b, c);
```

how can I convert back quaternion to my slider value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you *can* use e.g.

```
var localEulers = join.transform.localEulerAngles;

// did you btw mean to switch Y and X ?
slidery.GetComponent<Yslider>().value = localEulers.x;
sliderx.GetComponent<Xslider>().value = localEulers.y;
sliderz.GetComponent<Zslider>().value = localEulers.z;
```

however, note that there are multiple possible ways of representing a `Quaternion` in Euler angles so the returned values might not match which what you assigned! See [`Transform.localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html)